# SAS Studio sql query statement

Tags: sql, sas

Im new to SAS query.
Im trying to import excel file which has been done. And im trying to select to filter one of the column from another list of data from the same excel list..
Sorry for the grammar.. Let me put the question on..

Create the SAS data, Nonidentified that contains the information of customers who live in neither of the 16 cities. There are three attributes, Name, ID, and Gender in Nonidentified.
[image: This is the list of city]
And there will be a table store customer data which has one column called city.

Here is the code I have written so far:

```
proc sql; select * from list2; run;
```

Thank you guys...

Comment: Please tell what the query should be written..

Comment: This is my current code

Comment: So, what problem are you having with it?

Comment: i dont know how to use where statement to select the customer's city who does not in the Code list

Comment: We can only see what you show us and that's not much. It also looks like your last column may not have been read correctly? See the example under EXCEPT http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/sqlproc/69049/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1o6k7t8y56hobn1mup90vpf4ye6.htm

Comment: For your question to get responses please clearly indicate what you have, what you need and what you've tried.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are not showing us the fields in the tables List1 and List2. These are essential to answering the question. However, assuming that one of them contains data of the customer (Name,ID, Gender,City) here is the answer (I am assuming that the name of the imported table is 'Cities'):

```
proc sql;
create table nonidentified as
select name,id,gender
from List2
where City not in (select City from Cities);
quit;
```